# Determination of a off topic question

Tags: discussion, support

*Academia* says **For academics and those who enrolled in higher education**.

I just wanted to know that if I can ask a question related to **How** and **Why** to pursue a course (country specific) ?

Comment: Do you remember where you found the string "For academics and those who enrolled in higher education"? That's not the current tagline, and I'd like to update any inconsistencies.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately "how" and "why" questions about a particular course are likely to be [off-topic](https://academia.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for the following reasons:

1. "How" is usually either exceedingly generic or else highly dependent on a particular institution's processes and regulations.  For example, we cannot hope to tell you what to do in order to be admitted to a do Ph.D. in anthropology at Oxford.
2. "Why" is usually very opinion-based and individual in nature.  For example, my reasons for pursuing a degree in computer science were quite different than those of my office-mates.

That said, there may be cases where something is answerable; it's hard to know without knowing more about the question that you want to ask.

Answer (score 1):

Try to reword a question if it uses "how" or "why" and keep a few things in mind:

1). Is this only applicable to undergrads? (will be closed)

2). Is this question too broad? If there are a lot of working parts to your question or a lot of possible answers that could all be correct then you are likely to get closed (your question that is)

3).Is it opinion-based? @jakebeal did a good job at explaining this.

I have asked a "how" and "why" question before, but rewording the information and title is what kept me from getting closed. However, not every question that is a "how" or "why" question will be accepted even if it is reworded.